# Why do C++ lambdas cause an extra invocation of this destructor

Tags: c++, lambda

This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    inline Foo() {
        std::cout << "foo constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    inline ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "foo destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

void NotBroken()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::function<void(Foo&)> callback;
    callback = [](auto&) { // <- notice the auto&
        std::cout << "executed callback" << std::endl;
    };
    callback(foo);
}

void TotallyBroken()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::function<void(Foo&)> callback;
    callback = [](auto) { // <- notice the auto without &
        std::cout << "executed callback" << std::endl;
    };
    callback(foo);
}

int main()
{
    NotBroken();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    TotallyBroken();
}
```

This is the output:

```
foo constructor
executed callback
foo destructor

foo constructor
executed callback
foo destructor
foo destructor
```

Literally why, shouldn't the auto keyword without a & still detect that I'm passing the lambda into a std::function that expects a reference? I tested this with MSVC, Clang, and GCC, they all have this behavior.

The extra destructor invocation happens at the end of the lambda's execution FYI

Comment: Unlike destructor, class have several implicit constructors. You don't log all of them.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with my question. My problem is that an extra destructor invocation is being performed, what are you talking about exactly?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides mentions "optionally lvalue reference qualified"

Comment: @ProgramGamer There is no extra destructor.  A copy is being made and its destructor is being called when `callback` ends.  You haven't instrumented `Foo`'s copy constructor though, so you can't see the copy being constructed.

Comment: Ahh, I see what's being said now, fair enough, though I'll maintain that 273K didn't exactly make their point clear here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auto` by itself never deduces to a reference type.

You can think of your `std::function::operator()` as looking something like this:

```
void operator()(Foo& f)
{
    callback(f);
}
```

Since `callback` accepts its parameter by value, the type of its parameter is deduced as `Foo` and `f` is used to initialize a new object that is a copy of the object referenced by `f`.  When `callback` ends that object goes out of scope and is destroyed.